# How do black holes infinitely bend space-time when the bending is mass dependent and not density dependent?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, curvature, event-horizon, singularities

According to Einstein, mass bends the fabric of space-time. And nothing in the universe has infinite mass to infinitely bend space-time. So how do remnants of supermassive stars, i.e black holes infinitely bend space-time, so much so that even light can't escape it? How do black holes infinitely bend space-time when the bending is mass dependent and not density dependent?
Please forgive me for the inaccuracies I may have made.

Comment: The bending **is** density dependent. It is related to the stress-energy tensor and the dominant component of that tensor is usually the _density_.

Comment: Thank you for correcting my misconceptions! I was under the impression that only mass bends the fabric of space-time.

Comment: “*black holes infinitely bend space-time, so much so that even light can't escape*” - Note that “bending” has different meanings. In your statement above you refer to the metric “bending” at the horizon where the time dilation and length contraction diverge. And yet many on this site will point out that spacetime is “locally flat” at the horizon and claim “little or no bending” there.

Answer (score 3):

The two most well-known "black hole" solutions --- Schwarzschild (static) and Kerr (rotating) --- are both *vacuum* solutions to the Einstein equation (charged black holes, Reissner-Nordstrom and Kerr-Newman, are termed [electrovacuum solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrovacuum_solution)).  So, while the  Einstein equation is:
$$
G_{\mu \nu} = \frac{8 \pi G}{c^4} T_{\mu \nu} \quad \leftrightarrow \quad \text{curvature} \sim \text{ mass/energy}
$$
these black hole solutions were discovered under the assumption of *zero* mass and energy in the space time:
$$
T_{\mu \nu} =0 \quad \rightarrow \quad G_{\mu\nu} = 0
$$

The conclusion is that stable spacetimes can exist with a given (possibly extreme) curvature without any matter to cause it.  (Another "vacuum solution" to the Einstein equation is Minkowski space, the flat spacetime of special relativity).

Of course, we think that most black holes are formed by the collapse of matter into singularities (see the [Hawking Penrose singularity theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penrose%E2%80%93Hawking_singularity_theorems)), but black holes themselves (at least in their theoretical abstraction) are objects of pure spacetime curvature, no matter.

Comment: Correction made: the charged black holes Reissner-Nordstrom and Kerr-Newman have a non-zero stress energy tensor that accounts for a electromagnetic field, so they are not vacuum solutions. But, just as the $M$ in the Schwarzschild solution is just a parameter setting the curvature, the charged black holes contain no sources (no charge): the $Q$ is a parameter setting the curvature associated to the EM field.

Comment: These are indeed vacuum solutions, it is important to emphasize, i.e. they are solutions of Einstein's equations for R_ik= 0. But it is also true that, looking at them, the parameters M, J in the asymptotic Newtonian limit cases correspond to the mass and angular momentum of point-like or 1-dimensional sources. For this reason, we cannot claim that these are completely matter-free spacetimes, but rather that they have sources corresponding to the former.

Comment: @AttilaJanosKovacs I second your comment, because this answer makes a correct conclusion based on an incorrect interpretation. A “vacuum solution” is defined by the zero stress-energy tensor, which does **not** imply the absence of matter. During a gravitatiinal collapse, all star energy/matter is converted to the kinetic energy whose contribution to the stress-energy tensor is exactly canceled out by gravitomagnetism (momentum). So the stress-energy tensor becomes zero (a vacuum solution), but energy is conserved and all matter is still there giving mass to the black hole.

Answer (score 0):

The non zero terms of the Riemann tensor of the Schwartzschild black hole (spherical symmetry and no rotation), are fractions having $r$ or $r^3$ in the denominator, and having $GM$ in the numerator.

For example: $$R^1_{010} = -\frac{\frac{2GM}{r^3}}{1-\frac{2GM}{r}}$$
So the curvature tends to infinity as $r \to 0$ for any non zero mass.

Comment: The $M$ in the Schwarzschild metric is not "mass" it is simply a parameter.  Pure black holes have no matter, only curvature.

Comment: Yes. And if this "pure parameter" is zero, there is no curvature.

Comment: @BenH “$M$ *in the Schwarzschild metric is not ‘mass’*” - The fact that $M$ in the metric is mass is a common knowledge. What you mean to say is that this mass makes no contribution to the stress-energy tensor. “*black holes have no matter*” - Incorrect. Uncharged black holes have a zero stress-energy tensor. It is not the same as “no matter”. Matter configurations exist with a zero stress-energy tensor. For example, the stress-energy tensor of a photon is zero, because all energy of a photon is kinetic and thus frame dependent and can be made arbitrarily small  by a coordinate transformation.